# Starting out with CakePhp under XAMPP

Tags: php, cakephp, xampp

I downloaded XAMPP, started Apache & MYSQL, Apache runs on port 80, MySQL on 3306. 

When I navigate to `http://localhost` it redirects me to the XAMPP welcome page.

I downloaded Cake version 1.3.7, and extracted it into the htdocs, into this folder:

```
c:\xampp\apache\htdocs\app
```

I tried to access the index.php that exists in the folder, by visiting `http://localhost/app/index.php`, but I receive this error, 404:

> Object not found!The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.

I checked the `httpd.conf` file and the

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

line is uncommented.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you make a virtual host pointing to your app/webroot folder.

Answer (score 0):

try pointing your web browser to:

```
http://localhost/app/app/index.php
```